# Model not supported for deserialization

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting this error when trying to decode a Json Object

**Error:** Type 'realstate.Models.PesquisaModel.pesquisaClienteListModel' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

This is the string:

**JSON Object:**

```
jsonObj=[{
"idCliente":"2",
"nome":"Guilherme Longo",
"email":"guilhermelongo@outlook.com.br",
"tipoPessoa":"1",
"observacao":"Mais conteúdo",
"rg":"435180307",
"cpf":"341.307.948-41",
"cnpj":null,
"estado":"SP",
"cidade":"Ribeirão Preto",
"logradouro":"Rua",
"endereco":"Brigadeiro Tobias de Aguiar",
"numero":"469",
"bairro":"Independência",
"complemento":"Bloco A"
},
{"idCliente":"8",
"nome":"Guilherme Longo",
...
}]
```

Here is where I am facing this error:

```
public ActionResult dataSetClientes(string jsonObj)
{
   PesquisaModel.pesquisaClienteListModel items = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<PesquisaModel.pesquisaClienteListModel>(jsonObj);
   ...
 }
```

**EDIT 1:**

this is the Model:

```
public class PesquisaModel
{

    public class pesquisaClienteModel
    {
        public string idCliente { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string tipoPessoa { get; set; }
        public string observacao { get; set; }
        public string rg { get; set; }
        public string cpf { get; set; }
        public string cnpj { get; set; }
        public string estado { get; set; }
        public string cidade { get; set; }
        public string logradouro { get; set; }
        public string endereco { get; set; }
        public string numero { get; set; }
        public string bairro { get; set; }
        public string complemento { get; set; }                
    }

    public class pesquisaClienteListModel
    {
        public List<pesquisaClienteModel> item { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor question. Just fixed it.

Comment: Can you debug it and post the content of the jsonObj string on the controller side of things?

Comment: Did you pass your data: JSON.stringfy(/*myDataToSend*/)?

Comment: @Fals Thanks for all your reply. I was not converting JSON object to string. After using JSON.stringfy(/*myDataToSend*/) I am able to get the posted data in the controller. Please, post a awnser so I can accept it.

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo You are Welcome! I posted as awnsear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stringfy the content in the ajax function to make this work. Do this:

```
data = JSON.stringfy(/*myDataToSend*/)
```

Answer (score 1):

A class can be deserialized from a json array only if it implements IEnumerable. `PesquisaModel.pesquisaClienteListModel` doesn't. Instead, use the following:

```
   List<PesquisaModel> list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<PesquisaModel>>(jsonObj);
   PesquisaModel.pesquisaClienteListModel items = new PesquisaModel.pesquisaClienteListModel() { item = list };
```

Comment: Don't know if it helped the original poster, but fixed my issue, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do the serialization, the MVC model binder will do it for you. Change your action parameter to your custom type.

```
public ActionResult dataSetClientes(PesquisaModel jsonObj)
{

}
```